# Flutter image_picker plugin crash on android 12 take a image HEIF

Tags: flutter, dart, photo, flutter-image-picker

I have a problem on a big application (not reproductible with the image_picker sample) when some users take a picture, the application crash. I don't have a log because the debugger stop when the problem arrive and the application send nothing to crashlytics.

To describe the problem more precisely, when you open the camera, you can take a photo but when you validate the photo, the application crashes.
After investigation I found that this only happened with android 12 and HEIF quality photos.

I use flutter 3.3.x and image_picker 0.8.6.

Somebody have the same problem ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have the same problem, do you solved?

Comment: Same issue here ...